# Operations on tuples for each position individually

Tags: haskell, mapping, tuples

i want to do operations on tuples for each position individually. for example

```
pair_of_sums (a1,b1) (a2,b2) = (a1+a2, b1+b2)
```

or more general

```
sum_and_multiplication (a1,b1) (a2,b2) = (a1+a2, b1*b2)
```

is there any way to make it shorter? like:

```
pair_of_sums = xxx (+)
sum_and_multiplication = yyy ((+),(*))
```

Answer (score 4):

One possibility would be to use the [`bifunctors`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors) package which has some useful methods and functions for working with different types including pairs.

```
pair_of_sums = (<<.>>) . bimap (+) (+)
```

For pairs, [`bimap`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-4.2/docs/Data-Bifunctor.html#v:bimap) takes two functions and maps the first one over the first element and the second one over the second element (so, for this particular instance, we can view it as having the type `bimap :: (a -> a') -> (b -> b') -> (a, b) -> (a', b')`). We can see this in its definition

```
bimap f g ~(a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

(the `~` essentially just tells Haskell to be a bit more lazy here. It's not really relevant for our purposes.)

In this case, [`(<<.>>)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bifunctors-4.2/docs/Data-Bifunctor-Apply.html#v:-60--60-.-62--62-) takes a pair of functions and a pair and it maps each function in the first pair over the corresponding value of second pair. For this use, we can look at it as having he type `(<<.>>) :: (a -> a', b -> b') -> (a, b) -> (a', b')`).

We can again look at the source code for this function to get an idea of how this works for the `(,)` instance:

```
(f, g) <<.>> (a, b) = (f a, g b)
```

To see how these get put together, we can see that using `bimap` gives us this (specializing to the `(,)` instance for `Bifunctor`, since that is what we are using)

```
bimap (+) (+) :: Num a => (a, a) -> (a -> a, a -> a)
```

This gives us a pair of functions that will add the given value to the original value in each position of the pair. For example

```
λ> fst (bimap (+) (+) (3,5)) 10
13
λ> snd (bimap (+) (+) (3,5)) 100
105
```

Our composition with `(<<.>>)` allows us to turn this pair of functions into a function that takes a pair and gives a pair (which fits with the type signature for it I gave above).

Putting these together, we can have a more detailed look at the reduction performed in a call `pair_of_sums (3, 5) (10, 100)`:

```
pair_of_sums (3, 5) (10, 100)

((<<.>>) . bimap (+) (+))  (3, 5) (10, 100)         -- Definition of pair_of_sums

(\x -> (<<.>>) (bimap (+) (+) x))  (3, 5) (10, 100) -- Definition of (.)

(<<.>>) (bimap (+) (+) (3, 5))                      --
        (10, 100)                                   -- Function application

bimap (+) (+) (3, 5) <<.>> (10, 100)                -- Switch from prefix to infix

((+) 3, (+) 5) <<.>> (10, 100)                      -- After applying bimap for the (,) instance

((+) 3 10, (+) 5 100)                               -- Definition of (<<.>>) for the (,) instance

(13, 105)                                           -- Apply (+)
```

This is very similar to how the `Applicative` type class works, but it works with `Bifunctor` instead of `Functor` (actually, this is why the type class `(<<.>>)` belongs to is called `Biapply`). `bimap` is analogous to `fmap` and `(<<.>>)` is analogous to `(<*>)`.

One cool thing about using this technique to define these functions is that they would work for all of the type constructors that are instances of `Biapply`, not just `(,)`.

Answer (score 3):

```
import Control.Arrow

f = ((uncurry (***) .) .) . (***)

main = do
    print $ f (+) (+) (1, 2) (3, 4) -- (4, 6)
    print $ f (+) (*) (1, 2) (3, 4) -- (4, 8)
```

Here is how it works:

```
f                           = ((uncurry (***) .) .) . (***)
f op1 op2                   = uncurry (***) . (op1 *** op2)
f op1 op2  p1       p2      = uncurry (***) ((op1 *** op2) p1) p2
f op1 op2 (x1, y1)  p2      = uncurry (***) ((op1 *** op2) (x1, y1)) p2
f op1 op2 (x1, y1)  p2      = uncurry (***) (op1 x1, op2 y1) p2
f op1 op2 (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (op1 x1 *** op2 y1) (x2, y2)
f op1 op2 (x1, y1) (x2, y2) = (op1 x1 x2, op2 y1 y2)
```

Comment: That looks like a classic definition of overkill.